# Sql Procedure to count words of a given string

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I want to write a procedure in oracle sql developer to count the number of words in a given string. Please help me with this

Comment: Hey, I think you have hidden your code? Please try posting it again so we can see what you've tried so far.

Comment: The friendly people here at SO will be more willing to help you out if you show what you have tried yourself and where you got stuck. Maybe add some sample data and expected results to totally hit your response times out of the park.